# Ubuntu One app installation "waiting" on iPad

Tags: ubuntu-one, ipad

I would like to install the Ubuntu One app on my iPad. When I choose "install" in the app store, the Ubuntu One icon appears on my screen with a progress bar and the message "waiting." And it stays like that. I've tried removing it and restarting the installation and I get the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sometimes encountered this problem when installing any apps from on iOS devices. Try the following:

1. First, try turning the network devices off and on. Do this with all of them (Wifi, 3G, LTE). Even try putting it into and out of airplane mode.
2. If that didn't work, try rebooting the iPad.

Hope one of these helps.